How to add a default baggage header to all fetch requests in OpenTelemetry for Browser?
I'm using OpenTelemetry with JavaScript to instrument my web application. I've successfully set up tracing, and I can see that the traceparent header is automatically added to all fetch requests. Now, I want to add a default baggage header to all fetch requests as well.
Here's a simplified version of my current setup:
import { WebTracerProvider } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web';
import { getWebAutoInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-web';
import { ZoneContextManager } from '@opentelemetry/context-zone';
import { registerInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation';
import { W3CBaggagePropagator } from '@opentelemetry/core';

function initOtel() {
  const provider = new WebTracerProvider();
  
  provider.register({
    contextManager: new ZoneContextManager(),
    propagator: new W3CBaggagePropagator(),
  });

  registerInstrumentations({
    instrumentations: [getWebAutoInstrumentations()],
  });
}

initOtel();

This setup automatically adds the traceparent header to all fetch requests. However, I want to also add a baggage header with some default key-value pairs to all requests.
For example, I want something like this to be added automatically:
baggage: userId=12345,transactionId=abcdef
How can I modify my OpenTelemetry setup to achieve this? Is there a way to configure the W3CBaggagePropagator or use another mechanism to ensure this baggage is added to all outgoing requests?
I did not find any info in the docs https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/js/getting-started/browser/
as of today its still experimental.
I tried to set up a default baggage using the W3CBaggagePropagator like this:
const defaultBaggage = propagation.createBaggage({
  userId: '12345',
  transactionId: 'abcdef'
});

const propagator = new W3CBaggagePropagator();
const activeContext = propagation.setBaggage(context.active(), defaultBaggage);

provider.register({
  contextManager: new ZoneContextManager(),
  propagator: propagator,
});

I expected this to automatically add the baggage header to all fetch requests, similar to how the traceparent header is added. However, when I inspected the network requests, I didn't see the baggage header being included.
I also attempted to use the inject method of the propagator directly before each fetch call, but this seemed cumbersome and I was hoping for a more automatic solution that would work for all requests without manual intervention.
